# If $time = midnight, change $day

Tags: php, if-statement, time, switch-statement

If time is midnight 24:00+ $day must change to next day.. and $time reset.. *(Sorry for my english please)*

```
<?php

if ($time > "23") {
    $day + "1";
}
elseif ($time < "24") {
    $day + "0";
}

echo $day;

switch ($day) {
    case "1" : echo ("Mo"); break;
    case "2" : echo ("Th"); break;
    case "3" : echo ("We"); break;
    case "4" : echo ("Tu"); break;
    case "5" : echo ("Fr"); break;
    case "6" : echo ("Sa"); break;
    case "7" : echo ("Su"); break;
    default : echo ("-error-");
}

?>
```

Comment: your `switch` should be replaced by simple array. Not to mention doing math on strings.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where to begin... `$day` isn't initialised. Presumably you mean `$day = 1` or `$day += 1` depending on what you're doing. There's no such time as 24:00 as times run from 00:00 to 23:59.59. The PHP opening tag half way down is wrong. The switch statement is wrong. And...what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm intrigued to know what your intention was @Lexikonn. But your code will never keep track of the state of time. If you're trying to print out the day of the week based on clock changes just use the inbuilt PHP function `date`. For example: `echo date('D', time());`. Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve but I'd recommend you take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you're trying to print out the day of the week (e.g. "Mon") then this will do it:

```
echo date('D', time());
```

If you're trying to get a numeric representation of the day (1 = Monday, through to 7 = Sunday) then this will work:

```
echo date('N', time());
```

The latter is only available in PHP 5.1.0 or later.

Aside from syntax errors in your code, the key point is that your code will never keep track of changes in time. You need to refer to the time set on your server which is what `time()` is doing in the above code.

Hope this helps. if not please clarify what you're trying to get the code to do.

Comment: i need own time, no real :)

Comment: How ever you do it you need a source of time (time is constantly moving, and therefore cannot be coded as a PHP script which is stateless and will not track any changes like that... it has to have some reference to time).